# PHP: Google Translate 5000 characters limit

Tags: api, translate

I'm using this library for translating:

https://github.com/dejurin/php-google-translate-for-free

It's possible to translate more than 5000 characters with this library?
Or save the translated text to a txt and change from text translate to docs translate?

I mean this:

https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=docs&sl=en&tl=lb

Answer (score 1):

Based on what Google says, it is not possible to send more than 5,000 characters per request. Moreover, Google recommends that you send less than 5,000.
You can find it here under technical questions : [Google Translate FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/translate/faq)

Regarding the second question, ii is possible.

According to the website of the library the result of the translation is returned in the form of an array, so first of all you must do is convert the array into a string, separating each element of the array by what you decide (here I separate it by a blank space):

```
$arrayToString = implode(' ', $result);
```

Here $result is the array returned by the library. Now we just have to save the string in a txt file.

```
$file = 'path/to/file/filename.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $arrayToString);
```

Regards